# Check value of input type="number" robot framework

Tags: python, html, robotframework

I have the following html code:

```
<input type="number" name="student_id" min="0" max="100" step"1" value="0"/>
```

And I wanted to check the value of it using robot framework.
I have tried

```
Textfield Value Should Be  student_id  0
```

But it didn't work, string is empty therefore it always fails.
I am not sure what else I can use.
Also is there any way to change the value of input using the up and down arrow instead of using the following

```
Input Text  student_id  1
```

Thanks

Comment: for the latter one:  `${student_id} = ${student_id} + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Get Value?  If so, what does this return?

With regard to using the arrows on the number input, I'm sure this is possible but I'd ask you to consider, is this valuable?  i.e. is this something necessary you need to add to your test?